# How to pass parameters to Ajax to asp.Net core

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple controller:

```
[HttpPost("/api/LogError")]
public void LogError(string msg)
{
}
```

and javascript:

```
    fetch('/api/LogError', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'msg': tx
        })
    })
```

this doesn't work.
How should I properly pass a parameter?

Comment: Your fetch request isn't posting a string. It's posting an object that contains a property of type string. Have you considered changing your action method signature to accept an object that has a property named msg of type string?

Comment: thanks mason, but I don't want to change the method signature. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add data and content type like this:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```